R Markdown HTML DT datatable update values
Minimal Example of Rmd-Script:
library(DT)
df = data.frame(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), val = c(100, 150, 200, 100, 120))
datatable(df, filter="top")

After "Knit to HTML" the table is displayed correctly on the HTML-Page and can be filtered. Now is possible to show e. g. the mean of one column that is live updated when the table is filtered? Or also other variables?

Yes, it is possible to display the dynamic mean in the footer with the footerCallback option. Here is an example. The same code will work for any dataframe with numeric columns.
library(DT)

dat <- iris[1:4]

sketch <- htmltools::tags$table(
  tableHeader(names(dat)),
  tableFooter(rep("", ncol(dat)))
)

opts <- list(
  footerCallback = JS(
    "function(tfoot, data, start, end, display) {",
    "  var api = this.api();",
    "  var ncolumns = data[0].length;",
    "  for(var i = 0; i < ncolumns; i++) {",
    "    var columnData = api.column(i, {page: 'all', search: 'applied'}).data();",
    "    var total = columnData.reduce(function(a,b) {",
    "      if(isNaN(a)) return ''; return a+b;",
    "    })",
    "    var mean = total / columnData.length;",
    "    $(api.column(i).footer()).html(mean);",
    "  }",
    "}")
)

datatable(
  iris[,1:4], rownames = FALSE, container = sketch, 
  options = opts, filter = "top"
)


